# swapping indexError to eg. 0 in write row to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

i define csv header eg. `['0', '1', '2']` and i tried to fill it like this `writer.writerow({'0': x[0], '1': x[1], '2': x[2]})` but i havent got always list with 3 elements, sometimes there is 1 element, sometimes are 2. actually python return **IndexError**, but i think about how ignore this error and writing in this place 0. any ideas? best regard!

Comment: Read about [parameter extrasection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a bit more code. `list` looks like a row of data, perhaps show the data (I would suggest you avoid using a variable name called `list` as you would then lose the Python function `list()`).